# How can estimate $\pi$ with differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, pi

I know some method for estimation of $\pi$ .We can use Monte Carlo method to estimate $\pi $.We can use series to estimate $\pi $.

And my question is : Is there exist a (1 st order) differential equation or stochastic differential equation that can estimate $\pi $ ? or $\pi $ is a part of the solution, When we are implementing numerical iteration the solution close to $\pi $ ?

I tried some Matlab codes for Monte Carlo method like this below:

```
clear;  
N=100000; % the experiment event number  
r=1; %the circle radius  
n=0; % sucessful event number   
for i=1:N  
  x=-r+2*r*rand();  
  y=-r+2*r*rand();  
  if ((x^2+y^2)<=r^2)  
    n = n+1;
  end
end
pi_sim=4*n/N
```

How can I make a relation between $\pi$   and diff. equations ?
Thanks in advanced for any hint.

$$\textit{Specially, I am looking for Stochastic diff. Eq.}$$
Remark:

For example:If we solve this SDE $dx_t=(\mu-x_t)dt+\alpha dw_t$ we will see $\mathbb{E}[x_t] \to \mu $ so $$dx_t=(\pi-x_t)dt+\alpha dw_t \to (\mathbb{E}[x_t] \to \pi) $$ but this Non-interesting example (I made it by self)

Comment: $$ f''(x) +f(x)=0 ; f(0)=0; f'(0)=1$$
has unique solution $f(x)=\sin(x)$ so $\pi = 2f^{-1}(1)$

Comment: I don't know anything about SDEs, but if you can compute $\pi$ using an integral then you can compute it using a differential equation. For example, $\pi/4 = \int_0^1\sqrt{1-x^2}\,\mathrm dx$, so define $y'(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, $y(0)=0$, and you obtain $y(1)=\pi/4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, any probability distribution sums up to zero. So, you can invoke gaussian distribution, where,

$\int_{x=-\infty}^{x=\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} dx = 1$

To obtain $\pi$. You need to use estimated e though, if you want to calculate it numerically.

Comment: Why not use $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^2}$?

Comment: You can use it as well. Much simpler form. Note that $\frac{1}{2+x^2}$ is symmetric. So you may like to reduce the linit as well.

Comment: Make the integration interval finite, use $\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\arctan(1)=\frac{\pi}4$

Comment: +1, I wouldn't have thought of this had you not written it.

Answer (score 1):

For a first-order solution, you could use:

> **Proposition 0.** If $$f'(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}, \qquad f(-1)=0$$
>
> then $2f(1) = \pi$.

However, I think a second-order solution is a bit more conceptually satisfying. You could use:

> **Proposition 1.** $$\pi = \min_{\theta > 0} \,\left(\sin\theta \leq 0\right).$$

So just write a program that numerically approximates $\sin$ via the second order DE $$f'' = -f, f(0) = 0, f'(0)=1.$$ The moment $f(x)$ drops below $0$, return $x$ and it will be near to $\pi.$

Comment: I wrote this as Matlab program ,but a problem happened . $$f'(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}, \qquad f(0)=1$$ so $$4f(1)=\pi $$ (it must be).....but the answer is not close to $\pi$ this is my code ...clear;
$$N=500;\\
dt=1/N;\\
x=zeros(1,N);\\
x(1)=0;\\
for n=1:N-1\\
    x(n+1)=x(n)+sqrt(1-(x(n))^2)*dt;\\
end;\\
2*x(n)$$I can't understand :what's wrong!?

Comment: @Khosrotash, perhaps the last line should be $2*x(N)$? Or even better, shouldn't it be $4*x(N)$? You're integrating one quarter of the unit circle; the whole circle has area $\pi$, so you correctly surmize that $4\cdot f(1)=\pi$, hence you need to multiply by $4$. Also wouldn't the correct DE be $f'(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}, f(0) = 0$? After all, if we're integrating from $0$, then the area under the curve from $0$ should be $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by goblin's answer, but first order. Note that $\sin'(x)=\cos(x)$ and that
$$\cos(x)=\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}.$$
Hence we can use the first order differential equation
$$f'(x)=\sqrt{1-f^2(x)},\qquad f(0)=0$$
which has the solution $f(x)=\sin(x)$. As soon as this function reaches $1$ (or tends to exceed $1$), you abort the computation and your estimation is $x\approx \pi/2$ as this is where sine has its first maximum.

Comment: Wait is it $\sqrt{1-f^2(x)}$, or is it $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ that we're interested in? I wrote the latter in my latest edit...

Comment: @goblin I guess both are correct but different approaches. I assume you use $\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\pi/2$, right?

Comment: Yes, more or less; I use $\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-x^2} dx = \pi/2$. I figure if we're using left Riemann sums to solve the DE numerically, the one's on the left of $0$ will underestimate the area under the circle, and the one's on the right will overestimate it, so if we combine these we're going to get close to its actual value a little quicker.

Comment: What's your version based on? It looks a bit like the arclength formula...

Comment: @goblin It actually pretty much follows your approach of approximating $\sin$ by describing it by a differential equation, no use of any geometric idea here. The difference is that you used a second order, and I a first order differential equation. I than extract $\pi$ from features of the resulting curve $-$ you used a zero of $\sin$, and I use a maximum. In the end, this is how $\pi$ is defined initially.

Comment: It is better to use $\sin(\frac\pi6)=\frac12$ as the endpoint of the integration as a simple root is easier to localize than a maximum point.